# Switching to {controller}/{id}/{action} breaks RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to use proper `REST` urls with `MVC`.  To do that I switched default Routing from:

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

to

```
{controller}/{id}/{action}
```

so instead of:

```
/Customer/Approve/23
```

there is now

```
/Customer/23/Approve
```

ActionLink seems to work ok, but the following code in CustomerController:

```
[CustomAuthorize]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Approve(int id)
{
    _customerService.Approve(id);
    return RedirectToAction("Search");  //Goes to bad url
}
```

ends up on url `/Customer/23/Search`.  While it should be going to `/Customer/Search`.  Somehow it remembers `23 (id)`.

Here is my routing code in global.cs

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "AdminRoute", // Route name
        "{controller}/{id}/{action}", 
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { id = new IsIntegerConstraint() }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", 
        "{controller}/{action}", 
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

If I switch the two functions, `RedirectToAction` starts working, but using:

```
Html.ActionLink("Approve", "Approve", new { Id = 23})
```

Now generates `/Customer/Approve?id=23`, instead of `/Customer/23/Approve`.

I could specify direct urls like `~/Customer/23/Approve`, instead of using `ActionLink` and `RedirectToAction`, but would rather stick to functions provided by `MVC`.

Comment: I wonder if the UrlParameter.Optional on the id has any affect on this

Comment: The weird part is that UrlParameter has only one value "Optional", something like "Required" would probably make it work.

Answer (score 2):

When you use RedirectToAction(), internally, MVC will take the existing route data (including the Id value) to build the url.  Even if you pass a null RouteValueDictionary, the existing route data will be merged with the new empty route value data.

The only way around this I can see is to use RedirectToRoute(), as follows:

```
return RedirectToRoute("Default", new { controller = "Customer", action = "Search"});
```

counsellorben

Comment: Unfortunately that still keeps the custumer id in url, ending up with /Customer/23/Search

Answer (score 1):

Try passing in new (empty) RouteValueDictionary in your controller

```
return RedirectToAction("Search", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary{});
```

And here:

```
Html.ActionLink("Approve", "Approve", new { Id = 23})
```

I don't even know how can it pick up the Customer controller, since you are not specifying it anywhere. Try providing both controller and action to ActionLink helper.

Comment: If you call RedirectToAction("action") inside a controller, ControllerName is optional.  Seems to work the same if you do ActionLink in of the controller's views.  It just uses current controller.

Comment: yeah but for additional level of certainty you should specify controller when you are struggling with issues that you can't explain, don't you think?

Comment: Good point on "additional level of certainty".  I tried adding controller name, but no change.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the current route data to methon in your controller action:

```
return RedirectToAction("Search", this.RouteData.Values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part:

```
id = UrlParameter.Optional
```

may be resolve the problem; when you define "id" as an optional parameter, and you have the "Default" map, the "Default" and the "AdminRoute" are same together!
regards.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. Route values that were passed to my controller action were being reused when I tried to redirect the user with **RedirectToAction**, even if I didn't specify them in the new **RouteValueDictionary**. The solution that I came up with (after reading
counsellorben's post) with was to clear out the **RouteData** for the current request. That way, I could stop MVC from merging route values that I didn't specify.

So, in your situation maybe you could do something like this:

```
[CustomAuthorize]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Approve(int id)
{
    _customerService.Approve(id);
    this.RouteData.Values.Clear();  //clear out current route values
    return RedirectToAction("Search");  //Goes to bad url
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and was able to solve it by adding the id to the default route as well.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", 
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

If there is truly no id in your default route then you could also try:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", 
    "{controller}/{action}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = string.Empty });
```